# Go through the elements of two arrays as if they are ordered pairs

Tags: java, arrays

I want it to go through two arrays as ordered pairs (x,y)

```
(xcord[0],ycord[0])
(xcord[1],ycord[1])
(xcord[2],ycord[2])
```

...and so on

```
public int[] xcord = {74,177,288,27,132,479,144,408,19,80,264,380,406,491,18,85,165,206,296,106,49,25,13,78,89,145,138,167,221,234,245,371,449,347,299,379,440,291,462,393,282,338,448,318,398,456};
public int[] ycord = {11,26,41,58,54,71,99,83,121,152,124,113,129,152,214,227,187,206,191,262,276,343,472,407,447,336,458,416,470,334,270,182,185,227,294,276,302,379,356,402,438,417,427,481,475,480};

public void makeActors(){
    for(int x=0;x<46;x++){
        for(int y=0;y<46;y++){
            Box box = new Box();
            addObject(box,xcord[x],ycord[y]);
        }
    }
}
```

It goes through each item in the arrays but repeats xcord and ycord. What am I not seeing?

Comment: As a side note, I would use `.length` when traversing your arrays, instead of the literal bound you currently have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for a second `for` loop, and the first loop should serve the purpose if you just want to get the x and y coordinates from two different arrays. Considering that there is the same number of elements in both the arrays, this will work.

```
public int[] xcord = {74,177,288,27,132,479,144,408,19,80,264,380,406,491,18,85,165,206,296,106,49,25,13,78,89,145,138,167,221,234,245,371,449,347,299,379,440,291,462,393,282,338,448,318,398,456};
public int[] ycord = {11,26,41,58,54,71,99,83,121,152,124,113,129,152,214,227,187,206,191,262,276,343,472,407,447,336,458,416,470,334,270,182,185,227,294,276,302,379,356,402,438,417,427,481,475,480};

public void makeActors(){
    for(int x=0;x<46;x++){
        Box box = new Box();
        addObject(box,xcord[x],ycord[x]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, I'm really dumb. Thank You!

Answer (score 5):

You used two loops. If you want the values to be in lockstep then you only need one loop (and index). To be clear, I would use another index besides `x` or `y`. Like,

```
public void makeActors() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 46; i++) {
        Box box = new Box();
        addObject(box, xcord[i], ycord[i]);
    }
}
```

**or**, in Java 8+, with an `IntStream` like

```
IntStream.range(0, 46).forEachOrdered(i -> addObject(new Box(), xcord[i], ycord[i]));
```

Comment: I would defer to this answer. One improvement that can be made is using `i < xcord.length` to ensure that the magic number `46` is not used.

Comment: plus one for Java 8 implementation!